# how to access instant variable with rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a class like this.

```
require 'net/http'
class Foo
  def initialize
    @error_count = 0
  end
  def run
    result = Net::HTTP.start("google.com")
    @error_count = 0 if result
  rescue
    @error_count += 1
  end
end
```

And I want to count up `@error_count` if connection fails, so I wrote like this.

require_relative 'foo'

```
describe Foo do
  before(:each){@foo = Foo.new}

  describe "#run" do
    context "when connection fails" do
      before(:each){ Net::HTTP.stub(:start).and_raise }
      it "should count up @error_count" do
        expect{ @foo.run }.to change{ @foo.error_count }.from(0).to(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then I got this error.

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `error_count' for #<Foo:0x007fc8e20dcbd8 @error_count=0
```

How can I access instance variable with Rspec?

*Edit*

```
describe Foo do
  let(:foo){ Foo.new}
  describe "#run" do
    context "when connection fails" do
      before(:each){ Net::HTTP.stub(:start).and_raise }
      it "should count up @error_count" do
        expect{ foo.run }.to change{foo.send(:error_count)}.from(0).to(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `@foo.send(:error_count)` i guess it should work.

Update: [found in docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get)

```
expect{ foo.run }.to change{foo.instance_variable_get(:@error_count)}.from(0).to(1)
```

Comment: Also i suggest to use `let(:foo) { Foo.new }` according to http://betterspecs.org/, except that you are not in [let's not](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/lets-not) theme

Comment: I change the spec file as you suggested, but I get still `No method error`. And I don't want to make that attribute accessible from another class. Is there anything I can try?